# CSS weight in jQCloud, a jQuery plugin

Tags: php, jquery, css, arrays, tag-cloud

I need to create a **tag cloud** from a JSON file, which is made as follows:

```
{
   "data": "2023/02/14",
   "titolo": "San Valentino e un gatto a tre zampe",
   "anno_1": 1952,
   "anno_2": 1921,
   "anno_3": "",
   "luogo_1": "Italia",
   "luogo_2": "",
   "luogo_3": "",
   "persona_1": "Federico Seneca",
   "persona_2": "Luigi Broggini",
   "persona_3": "Luisa Spagnoli",
   "persona_4": "",
   "parola_1": "Perugina",
   "parola_2": "packaging",
   "parola_3": "ENI",
   "parola_4": "AGIP",
   "parola_5": "Futurismo"
 },
```

I extract "`persona_1`", "`persona_2`", "`persona_3`", "`persona_4`" from each entry using PHP and append all of them in an `array`:

```
$puntate = "docs/centra.json";
$html = file_get_contents($puntate);
$result = json_decode($html, true);
foreach($result as $key => $row) {
    $persona_1 = $row['persona_1'];
    $persona_2 = $row['persona_2'];
    $persona_3 = $row['persona_3'];
    $persona_4 = $row['persona_4'];
    array_push($persone,$persona_1,$persona_2,$persona_3,$persona_4);
}
```

Then I use [jQCloud (a jQuery plugin)](http://mistic100.github.io/jQCloud/index.html) to build the tag cloud:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var persone_array = [
<?php
foreach($persone as $personee => $freqpersone){
    echo '{text: "';
    echo $personee;
    echo '", weight: ';
    echo $freqpersone;
    echo '},';
}
?>
];
$(function() {
    $("#cloudpersone").jQCloud(persone_array);
    autoResize: true
});
</script>
```

The result can be seen [here](http://trovawiki.altervista.org/cosa_centra.php). All tags in the cloud are given a "`weight: 1`", although in the array `$persone` some words occur more often. Below is an extract from the array:

```
Array ( [] => 78 
[Albe Steiner] => 4 [Achille Castiglioni] => 4 [Bruno Munari] => 4 
[Marco Zanuso] => 2 [Richard Sapper] => 2 
[Andy Warhol] => 1 [Italo Lupi] => 1
```

I guess that the most frequent occurences should be shown with a higher weight. Is anything wrong? The "`weight`" in the plugin is described as "*the relative importance of the word - the range is arbitrary and will be linearly mapped to a discrete scale*".

Comment: Good code indentation and layout ___is for life, not just for Christmas___ and would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will be glad you took the time in the end.

Comment: _"Below is an extract from the array:"_ - there is no way that an array you filled by simply adding names to it via `array_push`, now all of a sudden contains the names "grouped" and with a count. Is there an additional `array_count_values` call that you left out, or something else that would actually count the occurrences of those names?

Comment: `$personeFrequencyArray = array_count_values($persone);
$personeFilteredArray = array_filter($personeFrequencyArray, function ($elementpersone) use ($my_valu) { return ($elementpersone >= $my_valu); } );
arsort($personeFilteredArray);`